# error while click event in Blazor wasm project

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, dropdown, blazor-webassembly

There is a click function for a dropdown menu option when the web page collapses to a tablet width screen. This click function was working fine before but not after I do publish my entire project and rerun the code in Visual studio 2019 Preview 16.10 version.

Here is the error message on the console in the browser. Help me with how I can resolve this error.

```
dropdown.js:143 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined
at o.r.show (dropdown.js:143)
at o.r.toggle (dropdown.js:139)
at Function.o.dropdownInterface (dropdown.js:371)
at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (dropdown.js:525)
at HTMLDocument.i (event-handler.js:119)
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the js extension of Bootstrap 5 helped me to run the page normally.

```
<!--<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>-->
```